# Polymer 1.0 - Where is the old core-submenu?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

One of the issues I'm having with the new polymer release is identifying which components are replacing the old ones. in this case I confused which component replaced with old [core-submenu](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-submenu.html) , I want to create Menu , with sub items , but in 1.0 version this component removed !

Comment: According to [this source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/blob/master/README.md) paper-submenu is planed, but still not in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the "core" items are now called "iron".

You probably want the iron-menu-behavior:
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-menu-behavior?active=Polymer.IronMenuBehavior

Comment: To say that **all** core elements are replaced with iron elements is not correct. Especially in that particularly case as there is no direct replacement for the submenu at this moment. Rather a replacement with paper-coremenu is planed, but is still not even in progress.